# Using dictionary and list together in Ansible

Tags: ansible

```yaml
mydatabases:
  group1:
    db_name: group1_database
  group2:
    db_name: group2_database
```

For example in this non working snippet, which you should be able to get an idea what I'm trying to do, I want to install multiple postgresql extensions (from a list) against the 2 databases `group1_database` and `group2_database` in the dictionary.

```yaml
name: add postgresql extension
postgresql_ext:
  name: "{{ item }}"
  db: "{{ item.value.db_name }}"
with_dict: "{{ mydatabases }}"
loop:
  - timescaledb
  - pg_partman
```

I've tried nested loops (which I didn't think it would work anyway) to no avail. Is there anyway I can do this to use a dictionary and list together or multiple dictionaries?

Comment: You can fake nested loops by putting an `include_tasks` in a loop, then having the inner loop inside the included file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists), which does exactly what you are looking for, translate a dictionary into a list.

Then use a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) of the two lists.

Giving the task:

```yaml
- postgresql_ext:
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
    db: "{{ item.0.value.db_name }}"
  loop: "{{ (mydatabases | dict2items) | product(extensions) }}"
  vars:
    extensions:
      - timescaledb
      - pg_partman
```

---

Here is a fake example with a debug instead of your Postgres task:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I need to install {{ item.1 }} on {{ item.0.value.db_name }}"
      loop: "{{ (mydatabases | dict2items) | product(extensions) }}"
      vars:
        mydatabases:
          group1:
            db_name: group1_database
          group2:
            db_name: group2_database
        extensions:
          - timescaledb
          - pg_partman
```

This would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'group1', 'value': {'db_name': 'group1_database'}}, 'timescaledb']) => 
  msg: I need to install timescaledb on group1_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'group1', 'value': {'db_name': 'group1_database'}}, 'pg_partman']) => 
  msg: I need to install pg_partman on group1_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'group2', 'value': {'db_name': 'group2_database'}}, 'timescaledb']) => 
  msg: I need to install timescaledb on group2_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'group2', 'value': {'db_name': 'group2_database'}}, 'pg_partman']) => 
  msg: I need to install pg_partman on group2_database

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Another approach is to use [`dictionary.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) in order to get a list of keys out of your dictionary.

Then use the [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) filter, once again.

Giving the task:

```yaml
- postgresql_ext:
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
    db: "{{ mydatabases[item.0].db_name }}"
  loop: "{{ mydatabases.keys() | product(extensions) }}"
  vars:
    extensions:
      - timescaledb
      - pg_partman
```

---

Here is a fake example with a debug instead of your Postgres task:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I need to install {{ item.1 }} on {{ mydatabases[item.0].db_name }}"
      loop: "{{ mydatabases.keys() | product(extensions) }}"
      vars:
        mydatabases:
          group1:
            db_name: group1_database
          group2:
            db_name: group2_database
        extensions:
          - timescaledb
          - pg_partman
```

This would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['group1', 'timescaledb']) => 
  msg: I need to install timescaledb on group1_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=['group1', 'pg_partman']) => 
  msg: I need to install pg_partman on group1_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=['group2', 'timescaledb']) => 
  msg: I need to install timescaledb on group2_database
ok: [localhost] => (item=['group2', 'pg_partman']) => 
  msg: I need to install pg_partman on group2_database

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This didn't work in Ansible 2.9.18 but works great in 2.10+ for both approaches